# Update BigQuery view with indirect schema changes

Tags: python, google-bigquery

When updating a view, indirect schema changes do not seem to be picked up.

#### Steps to reproduce

- Create `view1` with a field `field1` (e.g. `SELECT 1 AS field1`)
- Create `view2` selecting all fields from `view1`
- Update `view1` to also include `field2` (e.g. `SELECT 1 AS field1, 2 AS field2`)
- Update `view2` with the same query as before (due to [documented limitation](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/views-intro))

#### Desired outcome

- Schema for `view1` and `view2` including `field1` and `field2`
- View updates should be atomic

#### Actual outcome

- Schema for `view1` correctly updated (including `field1` and `field2`)
- Schema for `view2` is only including `field1`
- Selecting from `view2` does actually return `field1` and `field2`

I could delete `view2` and re-create it again but that wouldn't be atomic and there would be a time where the view is not available which is undesired.

I also tried to update the schema property of `view2` but that is refused with `Cannot add fields (field: field2)`:

> google.api_core.exceptions.BadRequest: 400 PATCH https://www.googleapis.com/bigquery/v2/projects/<project-id>/datasets/dataset1/tables/view2: Provided Schema does not match Table <project-id>:dataset1.view2. Cannot add fields (field: field2)

#### Question

Is there any way to update the view atomically while also updating the schema which was changed indirectly (a table/view the view selects from).

Note: of course my view2 would add additional fields and I could currently determine its schema by creating a new temporary view.

Note: the schema is important because tools such as the Data Studio's BigQuery connector are inspecting the schema.

#### Code to reproduce the steps

```py
# Python 3.6+
import google.api_core.exceptions
from google.cloud import bigquery


def delete_table_if_exists(client: bigquery.Client, table: bigquery.Table):
    try:
        client.delete_table(table)
    except google.api_core.exceptions.NotFound:
        pass


def full_table_id(table: bigquery.Table) -> str:
    # Note: the documentation says it should be separated by a dot but uses a colon
    return table.full_table_id.replace(':', '.')


def view_test():
    client = bigquery.Client()

    dataset_ref = client.dataset('dataset1')
    try:
        client.create_dataset(dataset_ref)
    except google.api_core.exceptions.Conflict:
        pass

    view1 = bigquery.Table(dataset_ref.table('view1'))
    view2 = bigquery.Table(dataset_ref.table('view2'))
    delete_table_if_exists(client, view1)
    delete_table_if_exists(client, view2)

    view1.view_query = 'SELECT 1 AS field1'
    view1 = client.create_table(view1)

    view2.view_query = f'SELECT * FROM `{full_table_id(view1)}`'
    client.create_table(view2)

    view1.view_query = 'SELECT 1 AS field1, 2 AS field2'
    client.update_table(view1, ['view_query'])

    client.update_table(view2, ['view_query'])
    print('view2 schema:', client.get_table(view2).schema)

    # trying to update the schema fails with 'Cannot add fields (field: field2)'
    view2.schema = client.get_table(view1).schema
    client.update_table(view2, ['schema'])


if __name__ == '__main__':
    view_test()
```

#### Bash example doing the same

```
#!/bin/bash

set -e

project_id=$(gcloud config list --format 'value(core.project)' 2>/dev/null)

bq mk -f dataset1

bq rm -f dataset1.view1
bq rm -f dataset1.view2

bq mk --use_legacy_sql=false --view 'SELECT 1 AS field1' dataset1.view1
bq mk --use_legacy_sql=false --view 'SELECT * FROM `'$project_id'.dataset1.view1`' dataset1.view2

bq update --use_legacy_sql=false --view 'SELECT 1 AS field1, 2 AS field2' dataset1.view1
bq update --use_legacy_sql=false --view 'SELECT * FROM `'$project_id'.dataset1.view1`' dataset1.view2

bq show dataset1.view2
```

### Update: Code with accepted answer

#### Python code

```py
def get_create_or_replace_view_query(view: bigquery.Table) -> str:
    return f'CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW {view.dataset_id}.{view.table_id} AS {view.view_query}'


def view_test():
    # ...
    query_job = client.query(get_create_or_replace_view_query(view2))
    query_job.result()
    print('view2 schema:', client.get_table(view2).schema)
```

#### Bash magic

```
bq query --use_legacy_sql=false 'CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW dataset1.view2 AS SELECT * FROM `'$project_id'.dataset1.view1`'
```

Comment: I don't understand a thing, if you say that view2 selects all fields from view1 the schema is actually a * star operator, so if you modify view 1 the fields are available in view 2 as well. The doc is clear about this limtation: The schemas of the underlying tables are stored with the view when the view is created. If columns are added, deleted, and so on after the view is created, the reported schema will be inaccurate until the view is updated. Even though the reported schema may be inaccurate, all submitted queries produce accurate results https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/views-intro

Comment: @Pentium10 I understand that view2's schema is not updated automatically. I am 'happy' to update it manually but I am not sure how to do that atomically.

Comment: @Pentium10 I added the step that was previously only mentioned further down that I tried to update view2 as well.

Comment: You need to use the PATCH method and not the update method see with that. On the other hand there is an alpha listed for information_schema, join that as well: https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/35906063

Comment: @Pentium10 do you have more information on that please? The `update_table` method seems to be using the `PATCH` HTTP method. I've added a more detailed exception which shows that (when I try to update the schema).

Comment: You could instead use CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW, right?

Comment: @ElliottBrossard that seems to work. Do you know whether it's atomic? If you post an answer then I could accept it.

Comment: I added an answer, and I can confirm that it's atomic, having reviewed the implementation :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You should use a `CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW` statement; see the [related documentation](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/data-definition-language#create_view_statement). BigQuery provides ACID semantics for all queries that perform table modifications, and `CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW` is no exception, so this replaces the definition and schema of the view atomically.